# What is the proper way of setting the page meta title in laravel

Tags: laravel

In many examples and documents I generally see that the page title is set via someController->main.blade.php->somePage.blade.php. Something like:

SomeController.php

```
public function someAction()
{
    $title = 'Some Title';
    return view('somePage', ['title'=>$title]);
}
```

main.blade.php

```
<head>
    <title> @section('title') | Page @show </title>
...
```

somePage.blade.php

```
@section ('title')
   {{$title}} @parent
@endsection
```

Wouldn't it be mode convenient to set it directly/only over the controller and blade layout file? I mean something like:

SomeController.php

```
public function someAction()
{
    $title = 'Some Title';
    return view('somePage', ['title'=>$title]);
}
```

main.blade.php

```
<head>
   <title>{{ $title }}</title>
...
```

Wouldn't it be better to use it in that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer not to assign the title from the controller - it's content and should be in the template from my point of view. I like to have a section in the template like

```
//layout file  
<title> FancyApp - @yield('title')</title>   

// Template 
@section('title', 'Page Title')
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the OPs question and seems like a less flexible strategy.  And the title is only content if it's not dynamic.  If you want flexible and dynamic templates then the title can be data just like the rest of the data you pass to the template.  
I see Skeletors point.  Why do the runaround of having `@yield('metaTitle', 'Default Title')` in your layout then `@section('metaTitle', $title)` in the child template when you can just have `{{ $title }} ` in the layout?  There must be a reason from the people that designed Blade.